# Basemap detect if within coordinates [+Python]

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am having some issues with Basemap. Not sure if what I want is feasible.

I have events with lat/lon. I would like to color states/cities according to those events. Similar to a heatmap. What would be the best way to do it?

So far my sketchy solution has been to make a meshgrid and countorf over the map, but I would prefer to color each state/city polygon individually instead.

However I was unable to find the coordinates of the borders or an easy way to verify given a coordinate if it is within the region.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome.  You're much more likely to get an answer if you include a minimum, complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: managed to solve it.
"for nshape, seg in enumerate(m.states):
coords=np.vstack(seg)

(lons,lats) = m(coords[:,0],coords[:,1],inverse=True)

 .... ## comparison with arbitrary coordinates 
"